# SAS proc SQL, Left Join, file name is too long

Tags: sql, sas, filenames, proc

When I did the left join

```
left join V_testtest_testtest_DIRECT_DAILY_FACT   a
```

I get the message below,
ERROR 65-58: Name 'V_testtest_testtest_DIRECT_DAILY_FACT' is too long for a SAS name in this context. Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Shorten the name?

Comment: The typical way to shorten the name is to create a view that is basically the table.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length for a table name in SAS is 32 characters - `V_testtest_testtest_DIRECT_DAILY_FACT` is 37 characters.  As @Gordon suggests, you need to shorten the name.

As @Reeza suggests, one way to do this is to create a view in the native DB that has a shorter name.  Alternatively, use pass-through syntax in your query.

Comment: The file is on the company server, I cannot shorten the name myself. Do I have other way to deal with it?

Comment: According to the code you posted, which doesn't have a library reference the table is in the default SAS `work` library.  If it's somewhere else you'll need to set up a library first.